# remove everything after 4th digit using regular expression ruby

Tags: string, digits

```
string="A.Brilliant.Young.Mind.2014.720p.BluRay.x264.YIFY"
```

I have a string like the one above, i am trying to prettify all my file names. I want to remove everything after the 4th digit found in the string so the name looks like this

```
"A.Brilliant.Young.Mind.2014"
```

so far using regular expression I can only remove everything before the numbers not after with the code below

```
string=string[/[^0-9]+/]
```

Comment: I figured it out, thanks to whom ever marked this as not enough effort. I always  put in effort. If the question was unclear it is as simple as asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me. Thank you once again and please be more considerate next time

```
string.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9. ]*\d{4}/)
```